# how to make a web application?

Tags: web-applications, frontend, backend

I need to make a document verification app which includes upload/download of a text file and also to display it with features including drag and select a paragraph which lets you make notes on it and also saves the data in excel file. I need guidance on how to go about it I'm using java- postman.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.